# Good-Turing smoothing when everything appears once

Tags: probability, smoothing

I would like to use Good-Turing smoothing to find the probability of the next type of fish I will catch. If I have caught the following already:

```
1 carp, 1 perch, 1 whitefish, 1 trout
```

Then N1 = 4, since I have seen four types of fish one time.

I know that with Good-Turing the probability of the next fish I catch being once I haven't seen previously is `P=N1/N`, so does this mean that `P(unseen) = 4/4 = 1.0`? This does not seem right, since that would make the probability of the next fish being a trout `p(trout)=0.0`. Is this correct, or is there something else I must do when the only `Nc` I have is `N1`?

Comment: Why are you calling it smoothing when you're not doing any smoothing? Reading Good's 1953 paper, it explicitly refers to smoothing that it looks like you haven't done.

Comment: That thing you say that you know ($p = N_1/N$) seems to actually be an approximation, and in this situation, I don't think it's a good one. Have you seen the [original paper](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/cogs502/GoodTuring1953.pdf)? Even if you used smoothing you appear to be well outside the level of data that the technique would be used for as is. The ideas can probably be adapted to this situation but the uncertainties would be very large indeed.